# django.template.loader can't find template

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I'm adding text content to a webapp. 
When I ran the app in the local server i had no issue, but when i uploaded the template to the server it returns me this error:

```
    Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://www.centros-sbc.com/domiciliaciones

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
    ('django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'suit',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'sbcweb',
    'south',
    'compressor',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'captcha')
Installed Middleware:
    ('django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware')

Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
**Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: **
**/home/manager/webs/sbc-web/sbcweb/templates/general/domiciliaciones.html (File exists)**

Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/general/domiciliaciones.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suit/templates/general/domiciliaciones.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/general/domiciliaciones.html (File does not exist)
**/home/manager/webs/sbc-web/sbcweb/templates/general/domiciliaciones.html (File exists)**
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/templates/general/domiciliaciones.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/templates/general/domiciliaciones.html (File does not exist)



Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/manager/webs/sbc-web/sbcweb/views/general.py" in domiciliaciones
27.     return render_to_response('general/domiciliaciones.html', response, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
29.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
170.         t = get_template(template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
146.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
139.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /domiciliaciones
Exception Value: general/domiciliaciones.html
```

here are my template loaders:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    #'django_mobile.loader.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

My template dirs:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(APP_PATH, "templates"),
)
```

the app path:

```
APP_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Here's the thing.
I just did few modifications on the text of /domiciliaciones.html processed the .po translation files and overwritted the translation files and the .html

I tried to fix the page returning to the original (without my changes) but it doesn't work neither.
If someone could help it would be great, I'm kind of desperate to fix that.
I don't know if you need more information about the app, just let me know!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I can answer your question! In Django 1.8.2, **Deprecated since version 1.8: Set the DIRS option of a DjangoTemplates backend instead.**,so,you should not set **TEMPLATE_DIRS**,In my opintion,you should set

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
       }
]
```

I spent a half of day to solve this problem in my WebApp! I guess this will help you!

Comment: Thank you. I am using Django 1.8.2 and I have exactly this problem. Been scratching my head for hours like oyu.